# Not able to run NPM Start after create-react-app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, create-react-app, npm-start

As I am learning the react for the first time I need to install the react-app but getting below error.
I have tried everything from the instructions in the error log and several other available solutions of StackOverflow but still not able to solve and getting the same error.

Here is the pic of below:

[image: Screenshot]

And here is the log:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Users\\Mr Rushil Dewaskar\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'start'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.5
3 info using node@v12.17.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle jsfx@0.1.0~prestart: jsfx@0.1.0
6 info lifecycle jsfx@0.1.0~start: jsfx@0.1.0
7 verbose lifecycle jsfx@0.1.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle jsfx@0.1.0~start: PATH: C:\Users\Mr Rushil Dewaskar\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;C:\Users\Mr Rushil Dewaskar\jsfx\node_modules\.bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\system32\Wbem;C:\Python38\Scripts\;C:\Python38\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\ArcSoft\Bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.4;C:\Program Files (x86)\Brackets\command;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Users\Mr Rushil Dewaskar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Scripts\;C:\Users\Mr Rushil Dewaskar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\;C:\Windows\System32\wbem\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\system32\Wbem;C:\Python38\Scripts\;C:\Python38\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\ArcSoft\Bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.4;C:\Program Files (x86)\Brackets\command;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Users\Mr Rushil Dewaskar\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\Mr Rushil Dewaskar\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Windows\System32\ variable;C:\Windows\System32\;
9 verbose lifecycle jsfx@0.1.0~start: CWD: C:\Users\Mr Rushil Dewaskar\jsfx
10 silly lifecycle jsfx@0.1.0~start: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'react-scripts start' ]
11 silly lifecycle jsfx@0.1.0~start: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle jsfx@0.1.0~start: Failed to exec start script
13 verbose stack Error: jsfx@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Mr Rushil Dewaskar\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:315:20)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Mr Rushil Dewaskar\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:286:5)
14 verbose pkgid jsfx@0.1.0
15 verbose cwd C:\Users\Mr Rushil Dewaskar\jsfx
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.18363
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Mr Rushil Dewaskar\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
18 verbose node v12.17.0
19 verbose npm  v6.14.5
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error jsfx@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the jsfx@0.1.0 start script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

**Please Help As soon as possible.**

Comment: are you using create-react-app to create new project?

Comment: My first inclination is to reinstall create-react-app with npx command, unless you've installed it locally, then npm will work fine.

Comment: Can you follow [these steps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62122386/2873538), probably using yarn?

Answer (score 1):

The solution to your problem is to remove the whitespaces in your username. In fact, the whitespaces anywhere in your path.
In your case, your username is Mr Rushil Dewasker. That's two whitespaces.
Change it to something without spaces and rebuild your project. It should work fine after that.
I had this problem once, myself.

Answer (score 0):

Well the error itself shows some way to solve this issue. Have you tried that?

Comment: Also check if you have the webpack dependency